# Ionic 6 ionViewWillEnter cannot read property 0 of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

I am learning ionic. So i have added data to an array declared in a service. When i go back to the lists page, `ngOnInit` will not execute if i have been to that page before. To load the data i need to use `ionViewWillEnter` or `ionViewDidEnter`. However, when i move the function call to the `ionViewWillEnter`i get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at DiscoverPage_Template (template.html:39)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9544)
    at refreshView (core.js:9413)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10579)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9210)
    at refreshView (core.js:9463)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10533)
    at refreshView (core.js:9437)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10579)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9210)
```

The only way i can get rid of the above error is by calling the function in both `ngOnInIt` and `ionViewWillEnter`.

```
loadedPlaces: Place[];
  listedLoadedPlaces: Place[]; //for virtual scroll

  constructor(private placesService: PlacesService, private menuCntrl: MenuController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInIt');
    this.loadData();
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(){
    this.loadedPlaces = this.placesService.places; //getter property
    //for the virtual scroll
    this.listedLoadedPlaces = this.loadedPlaces.slice(1);
  }
```

I have also tried declaring an empty array and then removing the function call from `ngOnInit`. In this case i get following issue:

```
core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at DiscoverPage_Template (template.html:39)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9544)
    at refreshView (core.js:9413)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10579)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9210)
    at refreshView (core.js:9463)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10533)
    at refreshView (core.js:9437)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10579)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9210)
```

My environment

```
node: v14.15.5
npm: 6.14.11
angular: 11.2.0
ionic: 6.13.1
```

How can i solve this issue?

Update:HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>

    <!--menu drawer-->
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="menu1"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>Discover Places</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">

  <ion-segment value="all" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
    <ion-segment-button value="all">All Places</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="bookable">Bookable Places</ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>

  <ion-grid>

    <!--open the side drawer manually -->
    <ion-row>
      <ion-button fill="clear" (click)="onMenuDrawerOpen()">
        Menu
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="apps-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark-done-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-row>

    <!--Featured place-->
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">

        <ion-card>

          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ loadedPlaces[0].title }}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{ loadedPlaces[0].price | currency }} / Night</ion-card-subtitle>
          </ion-card-header>

          <ion-img [src]="loadedPlaces[0].imageUrl"></ion-img>

          <ion-card-content>
            <div>{{ loadedPlaces[0].description}}</div>
          </ion-card-content>

          <div class="ion-text-right">
            <!--fill Clear mean no background -->
            <ion-button fill="clear" color="primary" routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/', 'places', 'tabs', 'discover', 'place', loadedPlaces[0].id, 'detail']">
              More
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="star"></ion-icon>
              <ion-icon slot="end" name="arrow-forward-circle-outline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </div>

        </ion-card>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <!--Other places-->
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">

        <!--since using scroll, removed the for loop from the ion-item moved it to the ion-virtual-scroll-->
        <!--it takes the items property -->
        <!--get the approxItemHeight using the dev tools and picking the height of an ion-item. The default is 40px-->
        <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="listedLoadedPlaces" approxItemHeight="60px">

        <!--<ion-list>-->

          <!--Excluding the featured item above-->
          <!--<ion-item *ngFor="let place of loadedPlaces.slice(1); let i = index" [routerLink]="['/', 'places', 'tabs', 'discover', 'place', place.id, 'detail']" detail>-->
          <ion-item [routerLink]="['/', 'places', 'tabs', 'discover', 'place', place.id, 'detail']"
            detail
            *virtualItem="let place">
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
              <ion-img [src]="place.imageUrl"></ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>{{ place.title}}</h2>
              <p>{{ place.description }}</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>

        <!--</ion-list>-->

      </ion-virtual-scroll>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: please share html code

Comment: @RaviAshara html added to the question.

Comment: Try `loadedPlaces[0]?.title` or if in loadedPlaces is object set `loadedPlaces?.title`

Comment: Thanks, we got to the same solution at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check for the null. Changing to following fixed the issue, did it for all the properties:

```
loadedPlaces[0]?.title
```